# JQuery CSS ThemeRoller Mobile: Applying Theme A, B, C to different pages

Tags: jquery, css, html, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-themeroller

I'm trying to design a mobile app based on [Themeroller CSS](http://jquerymobile.com/themeroller/) generated theme. Additionally the package includes:

- jQuery 1.9.1
- jQuery 1.3.0
- jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.0.min.css

Themeroller generated CSS file has three different themes (for three pages):

- Theme A (Blue)
- Theme B (Red)
- Theme C (Gray)

I've created everything in HTML5 and applied all above mentioned sources, but the result is all pages are in Theme A instead of another themes B and C respectively. Here is the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dozent/jT7pK/) version of the project.

I can not find where I'm going wrong. Any ideas?

```
<!-- Page 1 -->
<div data-role="page" id="firstPage" data-theme="a">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="inline">
        <h1>Page 1</h1>
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-theme="a">!</a>
        <a href="#secondPage" data-role="button" data-theme="a">p2</a></div>
    <div data-role="content" data-theme="a" align="center">
    <!-- Content -->
    <h1>Test1 Test1</h1>
    <p>Text1 Text1</p>
    <select name="sound" data-role="slider" data-theme="a">
        <option value="0">Off</option>
        <option value="1" selected="selected">On</option>
    </select></div>
    <!-- /Content -->
</div>
<!-- Page 2 -->
<div data-role="page" id="secondPage" data-theme="b">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="inline">
        <h1>Page 2</h1>
        <a href="#firstPage" data-role="button" data-theme="b">p1</a>
        <a href="#thirdPage" data-role="button" data-theme="b">p3</a></div>
<div data-role="content" data-theme="b" align="center">
    <!-- Content -->
    <h1>Test2 Test2</h1>
    <p>Text2 Text2</p>
    <select name="sound" data-role="slider" data-theme="b">
        <option value="0">Off</option>
        <option value="1" selected="selected">On</option>
    </select></div>
    <!-- /Content -->
</div>
<!-- Page 3 -->
<div data-role="page" id="thirdPage" data-theme="c">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="inline">
        <h1>Page 3</h1>
        <a href="#secondPage" data-role="button" data-theme="c">p2</a>
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-theme="c">!</a></div>
<div data-role="content" data-theme="c" align="center">
    <!-- Content -->
    <h1>Test3 Test3</h1>
    <p>Text3 Text3</p>
    <select name="sound" data-role="slider" data-theme="c">
        <option value="0">Off</option>
        <option value="1" selected="selected">On</option>
    </select></div>
    <!-- /Content -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First this is a bug with jQuery Mobile but you can make it work if you remove data-theme from all of your **`data-role="page"`** div and move it to you **`data-role="header"`** div.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/ceBAj/

```
<!-- Page 1 -->
<div data-role="page" id="firstPage">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="inline">
        <h1>Page 1</h1>
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-theme="a">!</a>
        <a href="#secondPage" data-role="button" data-theme="a">p2</a></div>
    <div data-role="content" data-theme="a" align="center">
        <!-- Content -->
        <h1>Test1 Test1</h1>
        <p>Text1 Text1</p>
        <select name="sound" data-role="slider" data-theme="a">
            <option value="0">Off</option>
            <option value="1" selected="selected">On</option>
        </select></div>
        <!-- /Content -->
</div>

<!-- Page 2 -->
<div data-role="page" id="secondPage">
    <div data-theme="b" data-role="header" data-position="inline">
        <h1>Page 2</h1>
        <a href="#firstPage" data-role="button" data-theme="b">p1</a>
        <a href="#thirdPage" data-role="button" data-theme="b">p3</a></div>
    <div data-role="content" data-theme="b" align="center">
        <!-- Content -->
        <h1>Test2 Test2</h1>
        <p>Text2 Text2</p>
        <select name="sound" data-role="slider" data-theme="b">
            <option value="0">Off</option>
            <option value="1" selected="selected">On</option>
        </select></div>
        <!-- /Content -->
</div>

<!-- Page 3 -->
<div data-role="page" id="thirdPage">
    <div data-theme="c" data-role="header" data-position="inline">
        <h1>Page 3</h1>
        <a href="#secondPage" data-role="button" data-theme="c">p2</a>
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-theme="c">!</a></div>
    <div data-role="content" data-theme="c" align="center">
        <!-- Content -->
        <h1>Test3 Test3</h1>
        <p>Text3 Text3</p>
        <select name="sound" data-role="slider" data-theme="c">
            <option value="0">Off</option>
            <option value="1" selected="selected">On</option>
        </select></div>
        <!-- /Content -->
</div>
```

Comment: Got it, thank you. However about one more issue wanted to ask you, as you see `on/off` options aren't changing according to the theme (A, B, C). Have you any idea to apply to this options above mentioned themes (colors)?

Comment: You didn't changed them in your theme. I have already checked that. If you can mail me your theme and I will fix it for you. But mail me your uncompressed theme. theme roller can't load compressed source. My mail is: dragan.gaic@gmail.com

Comment: The whole Themeroller package (zip file) has been sent to your adress. Thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look at my jsFiddle again. Problem here is that current jQuery Mobile don't have a separate class ui-btn-active for every theme so active button / slider background is always blue. You can change it with this css: .ui-btn-active {
    background: red !important;            
}        
 or you can use jQuery and change this class on every separate page.

Comment: Anyway thanks for your contribution. I decided to change the option to `checkbox` to avoid the color ;)

Comment: Whatever server your purpose, I hope jQM developers will ix this.